# How to load PathCchCanonicalizeEx at run-time?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-8, backwards-compatibility

I'm trying to use the [PathCchCanonicalizeEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API but also make my app available on OS earlier than Windows 8. So I wanted to load it using LoadLibrary but I can't seem to figure out what library it comes in?

Comment: Well, if all else fails, you can just use Dependency Walker and load each system DLL to see which one contains the exported function (http://www.dependencywalker.com)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: It gives me `api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll` that I've never heard of.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh802935%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  Are you running Windows 8.1?  If you are, just call `LoadLibrary()` with that name and see if it returns a valid handle.

Comment: @BSH: Yes, I'm running it on 8.1. And, no, I don't want it to work on Windows 7 or earlier. I'm just not sure if I can use `LoadLibrary("api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll");` on Windows 8? I tried and it works though.

Comment: Any news? I woud not try to load it explicitly ... 
[MDSN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/hh707084(v=vs.85).aspx):
"Minimum supported client Windows 8 [desktop apps only]"

Comment: In the question, you say "on OS earlier than Windows 8", but in your comments you state "I don't want it to work on Windows 7 or earlier". Which one is it?

Comment: @Liviu: No, I just went with `LoadLibrary(L"api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll");`. I couldn't find any other way. As for your other point, what I meant is that I didn't want to link statically to it, which would've prevented my app from running on OS earlier than Windows 8.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: hey, good catch. It took you 5 yrs to do that but you got it!