# Break build for not matching Windows versions: Pathcch.h functions

Tags: winapi, windows-8, backwards-compatibility, windows-shell

This application has to run on Windows 7, so it defines "`#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7`". [`PathAllocCanonicalize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707084(v=vs.85).aspx) is `Windows 8 [desktop apps only]`, but the build works, so the surprise appears later on, at runtime, on Win7: the application cannot start because "api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll" is missing. The header, Pathcch.h, defines something:

```
/* APISET_NAME: api-ms-win-core-path-l1 */

#ifndef _APISET_PATH_VER
#ifdef _APISET_MINCORE_VERSION
#if _APISET_MINCORE_VERSION >= 0x0100
#define _APISET_PATH_VER 0x0100
#endif
#endif
#endif
```

Can it be used ... somehow? 
Or, if this is shell, can I install something in Windows 7 for having it work?

**EDIT** `PathAllocCanonicalize` is in `Pathcch.h`, which ignores `_WIN32_WINNT`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131602/how-to-load-pathcchcanonicalizeex-at-run-time

Comment: Run `dumpbin /imports` on your compiled binary. I'd be willing to bet that the library is being linked in. If it is, you need to pull in the reference at runtime using `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`

Comment: What I am wondering is if the build could be break so I can detect early a problem like this. This is the intention of `_WIN32_WINNT`, so why isn't the case for the `Pathcch.h` functions ?

Comment: If you're calling the function directly than the linker will include it in your import table. Since the library that the linker refers to when determining imports has the function, it is able to resolve it. If you remove direct function calls and instead use `GetProcAddress` to fetch a function pointer, then the linker doesn't know about the dependency, and therefore won't add that to your import table. As far as causing a build failure, you could try writing a post build script to check the module imports, but I'd have to defer to others here for any kind of better solution.

Comment: Write it manually? `#if versionMacroOfChoice < minimumValue #error can't do that #endif`

Comment: @andlabs Where? In a `Pathcch.h` wrapper? And force everybody to use it?

Comment: @Liviu in your program's own header files. Certainly you have a `myApp.h`?

Comment: @andlabs It is a big app, but each unity has some `stdafx.h`. Your solution is not for the compiler, but it could be a clear rule when seen in a header. Could you write an answer, please?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft ended extended support for Windows 7.

This substitution for api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll may help:
https://github.com/nalexandru/api-ms-win-core-path-HACK

It's tested with Blender.

Answer (score 0):

There's no compiler magic involved in the version macros; all that happens is that instead of having

```
extern void f(void);
```

in the header files, Microsoft has

```
#if _VERSION >= _MIN_VERSION
extern void f(void);
#endif
```

(or something similar to that). This uses the preprocessor as a filter, making the functions undeclared on unsupported systems (which is why you get a compiler warning about undeclared symbols).

So you can just do this yourself in your project's own header files. The `#error` directive (which is part of standard C and C++) will spit out a  compiler error with the message of your choice. Since you have already decided to `#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7` in your source, you could stick something like this in one of your project's own header files, such as `stdafx.h`:

```
#if _WIN32_WINNT < _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8
#error Sorry, this program requires Windows 8 or newer.
#endif
```

(You'll have to substitute the actual value of `_WIN32_WINNT_WIN8` if you put this before `#include <windows.h>`.) After including these lines, the first source file that has that header file in will cause the compiler to error out if someone changes `_WIN32_WINNT` to a value that's lower than Windows 8.

Hopefully this will suit your needs.

Comment: I do not see how can this prevent someone from including `Pathcch.h` somewhere else and using it. I thought your suggestion was to force this header inclusion in stdafx.h together with a _WIN32_WINNT validation.